# Fixing barplot with shifted values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following data frame and code that produces a barplot.

```
#create dataframe
rG_activity <- c("-0.409", "-0.409", NA, "0.268", "0.268", "0.227", "0.092", "-0.220")
rG_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.263)", NA, "(0.222, 0.602)", "(0.282, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.220)", "(-0.222, 0.252)")
rG_task_persistence <- c("-0.409", "-0.409", "-0.209", "-0.262", "-0.225", "-0.292", "-0.062", "-0.292")
rG_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.262)", "(-0.679, -0.222)", "(-0.560, -0.222)", "(-0.296, -0.086)", "(-0.272, 0.227)", "(-0.507, -0.072)")
rE_activity <- c("-0.098", "-0.098", NA, "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.052", "-0.022", "0.058")
rE_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", NA,"(-0.022, 0.222)", "(-0.298, 0.028)", "(-0.228, 0.220)", "(-0.266, 0.220)", "(-0.225, 0.222)")
rE_task_persistence <- c("-0.098", "-0.098", "-0.098", "0.092", "-0.002", "0.202", "0.027", "0.205")
rE_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.262, 0.062)", "(-0.065, 0.252)", "(-0.272, 0.270)", "(-0.065, 0.272)", "(-0.222, 0.206)", "(-0.072, 0.280)")
age <- c("intercept", "slope", "36","30", "24", "18", "12", "6")
df <- data.frame(age, rG_activity, rG_activity_error_intervals, rG_task_persistence, rG_task_persistence_error_intervals, rE_activity, rE_activity_error_intervals, rE_task_persistence, rE_task_persistence_error_intervals)

#produce plot
df_tidy <- df |>
rename_with(~ paste0(.x, "_value"), !c(age, ends_with("intervals"))) |>
pivot_longer(-age,
names_to = c("what", "type", ".value"),
names_pattern = "^(.*)_(activity|task_persistence)_(value|error_intervals)$"
) |>
separate_wider_regex(error_intervals,
patterns = c("\\(", lower = ".*?", ",", upper = ".*?", "\\)")
) |>
mutate(across(c(value, lower, upper), as.numeric),
age=factor(ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(age)==T),as.factor(age),age)))

df_tidy$what <- factor(df_tidy$what, levels = c("rG", "rE"))

df_tidy <- df_tidy |>
  mutate(
    ci_upper = pmax(upper, lower),
    ci_lower = pmin(upper, lower),
    y_label = if_else(value > 0, ci_upper, ci_lower) + .1 * if_else(value > 0, 1, -1),
    vjust = if_else(value > 0, 0, 1)
  )

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(age, value, fill = what)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), position = position_dodge(width = .9), width = .25) +
  geom_text(size = 2.75,
            aes(
              label = value,
              y = y_label,
              vjust = vjust,
            ),
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)
  ) +
  scale_fill_grey(
    start = 0.475,
    end = 0.8,
    na.value = "red",
    aesthetics = "fill"
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("age 6", "age 12", "age 18", "age 24", "age 30", "age 36", "slope", "intercept"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, .3)) +
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Correlation", fill = NULL)
```

Looking at the data frame..

```
> df.new[c("age", "rG_activity", "rG_task_persistence")]
        age rG_activity rG_task_persistence
1 intercept      -0.409              -0.409
2     slope      -0.409              -0.409
3        36        <NA>              -0.209
4        30       0.268              -0.262
5        24       0.268              -0.225
6        18       0.227              -0.292
7        12       0.092              -0.062
8         6      -0.220              -0.292
```

You see that, for instance, rG_activity at age 6 is -0.220. Yet -0.220 is displayed on age 36 on the graph above (see top bar plot, age 36). We see the same thing for rG_task_persistence at age 6, which is -0.292. This is displayed on age 36 on the graph, when we really want it at its proper age (age 6). All of the values seem to be shifted (e.g, rG_activity of .227 is displayed on age 12 when it should be on age 18). I could be wrong, but I suspect that offending/needing-to-be-tweaked line might be `age=factor(ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(age)==T),as.factor(age),age)))`. Would appreciate any help on how to fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your code exactly, but I think your problem is that you have just changed the `labels` in the `scale_x_discrete` without actually changing the order the bars are drawn in.

So the bars are in alphabetical order, with "Age 12" first and "Age 6" last, but the labels do not match.  You can fix it like I have below, by setting the `limits` to be the order of the actual `age` variable values, and then setting the `labels` for each value as a named vector.  There might be a better way, but this works!

Code below, I used `data.table` to do the wrangling because I don't know `tidyverse` very well.  The `scale_x_discrete` line is the one you need to look at.

Note you have some values that are outside the interval limits, but I'm sure you know that, I've just plotted the data as it was presented..

```
rG_activity <- c("-0.409", "-0.409", NA, "0.268", "0.268", "0.227", "0.092", "-0.220")
rG_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.263)", NA, "(0.222, 0.602)", "(0.282, 0.752)", "(0.229, 0.726)", "(-0.259, 0.220)", "(-0.222, 0.252)")
rG_task_persistence <- c("-0.409", "-0.409", "-0.209", "-0.262", "-0.225", "-0.292", "-0.062", "-0.292")
rG_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.263)", "(-0.556, -0.262)", "(-0.679, -0.222)", "(-0.560, -0.222)", "(-0.296, -0.086)", "(-0.272, 0.227)", "(-0.507, -0.072)")
rE_activity <- c("-0.098", "-0.098", NA, "0.256", "-0.225", "-0.052", "-0.022", "0.058")
rE_activity_error_intervals <- c("(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", NA,"(-0.022, 0.222)", "(-0.298, 0.028)", "(-0.228, 0.220)", "(-0.266, 0.220)", "(-0.225, 0.222)")
rE_task_persistence <- c("-0.098", "-0.098", "-0.098", "0.092", "-0.002", "0.202", "0.027", "0.205")
rE_task_persistence_error_intervals <- c("(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.261, 0.064)", "(-0.262, 0.062)", "(-0.065, 0.252)", "(-0.272, 0.270)", "(-0.065, 0.272)", "(-0.222, 0.206)", "(-0.072, 0.280)")
age <- c("intercept", "slope", "36","30", "24", "18", "12", "6")
df <- data.frame(age, rG_activity, rG_activity_error_intervals, rG_task_persistence, rG_task_persistence_error_intervals, rE_activity, rE_activity_error_intervals, rE_task_persistence, rE_task_persistence_error_intervals)

library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# Reshape the data into long format.  Look at help for data.table::melt
df_tidy <- melt(df , measure.vars = list(values=c("rG_activity","rG_task_persistence","rE_activity","rE_task_persistence"),
                              intervals=c("rG_activity_error_intervals","rG_task_persistence_error_intervals","rE_activity_error_intervals","rE_task_persistence_error_intervals")))

# melt() left this column as a string so I converted it to numeric.
df_tidy[ , values:=as.numeric(values)]

# now we need to get the intervals from the string that contains them.  data.table has tstrsplit to do this (tidyverse has 'separate')
df_tidy[ , c("lci", "uci") := tstrsplit(gsub("[()]","",intervals),split=",",type.convert = TRUE)]

# when I melted the data I lost the labels on the different conditions. this will put them back.
df_tidy[ , condition := c("rG_activity", "rG_persistence", "rE_activity", "rE_persistence")[variable]]

# now i separate this out into the 'what' and 'type' columns that i need.
df_tidy[ , c("what","type") := tstrsplit(condition,split="_")]

ggplot(df_tidy) + 
  aes(x=age, y=values, ymin=lci, ymax=uci,fill=what) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.9),width=0.25) + 
  facet_wrap(~type, ncol=1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgrey", "lightgrey"))+
  geom_text(size=2.75,aes(label=values,y=if_else(values > 0, uci, lci) + .1 * if_else(values > 0, 1, -1)),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("6", "12", "18", "24", "30", "36", "slope", "intercept"),
                   labels = c("6"="Age 6", "12"="Age 12", "18"="Age 18", "24"="Age 24", "30"="Age 30", "36"="Age 36", "slope", "intercept"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. Would it be possible for you to explain what's happening in each line so I can really understand what's going on?

Comment: I've added some annotation to the data.table lines, but you should look the data.table vignettes if you want to understand this package.

Comment: Much appreciated. How would I go about changing the order of the columns such that rG comes before rE?

Comment: Turn `what` into a factor and set the levels in the order you want them.  In my code that would be: `df_tidy[ , what := factor(what, levels=c("rG", "rE"))]`